# Selecting features that do not touch other features in same layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, topology, select-by-location, select-by-expression

In QGIS I have a polygon layer where there are some isolated objects which do not touch other objects in the same layer. They are isolated and therefore I do not need them.

How can I select these ones?

Comment: I think this question must be more precised. 
1. Have you got the coordinates in the data attribute table?
2. Can you simply select them and delete if you don't need them?

Comment: I do not have coordinates and sadly there are too much for selecting all manual

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the function `overlay_disjoint()` ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#overlay-disjoint)):

```
overlay_disjoint(@layer)
```

via "Select by expression" ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-expression)) to select the features. Then you can delete them or do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. That worked :)